# Display Dynamic checkbox with value depending on placeholder's value

Tags: javascript, dynamic, checkbox

I need to add chckboxes in my page based on the value in a placeholder's textbox on the same page.When the page loads, it should check the placeholder textbox's value.If textbox value is "A" display 2 checkboxes on the page with values B and C.If the textbox value is "B" or "C" display only one checkbox on the page with value "A".How can I do this?Please help

Comment: Are you using any framework? jQuery or such?

Answer (score 0):

Saying this is your example (using jQuery):

```
<div id="placeholder"><input name="textbox" type="text" value="A" /></div>
```

You would need something of the sort of this

```
$(function() {
    var value = $('#placeholder').find('input[name="textbox"]').val();
    if (value == "A") {
         var checkboxB = $('<input type="checkbox" value="b"/>'),
             checkboxC = $('<input type="checkbox" value="c"/>');
         $('#placeholder').append(checkboxB, checkboxC);
    }
    else {
         // ...
    }
}
```